# What does ${$item} mean?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, braces, variable-variables

I'm not able to understand braces goal in the situation below and I find no serious documentation about braces usage.

See the example below:

```
 $var = array('a','b','c','d');

 foreach($var as $item){

       ${$item} = array();

 }
```

I'm non understanding `${$item}` meaning.

I've tried with `var_dump` before and after foreach loop but it seems nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It creates 4 empty arrays:

```
$a, $b, $c, $d // arrays now
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. Let me ask a question to you. Do you think this is a good practice ? It seems "dark programming"

Comment: @alesdario: Meanwhile its treated as "bad practice", but in some (minor) cases it may make things easier, or such. In fact I didn't used it ever.

Answer (score 2):

Curly braces create a variable with same name as string provided inside the curly braces.
In your code, it creates 4 new variables $a,$b,$c,$d by taking strings from the array
$var .

Here is an example to see the difference in variables created in your code:
http://codepad.org/E2619ufe

```
<?php

$var = array('a','b','c','d');
$currentState = get_defined_vars();

foreach($var as $item){

       ${$item} = array();

 }

$newState =  get_defined_vars();
$newVariables = array_diff(array_keys($newState),array_keys($currentState));
var_dump($newVariables);

?>
```

Here is an example usage of curly braces:
http://codepad.org/KeE75iNP

```
<?php

${'myVar'} = 12345;
var_dump($myVar);

/* also helpful when the variable name contains $ due to some reason */

${'theCurrency$'} = 4000;
var_dump(${'theCurrency$'});

/* uncomment line below, it will raise syntax error */
//var_dump($theCurrency$); 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes exactly  it creates 4 empty arrays , you are creating variables on runtime , thats the usage of braces . here is examples of the usage of braces : [braces in php](http://cowburn.info/2008/01/12/php-vars-curly-braces/)

Answer (score 0):

Anything you put in curly brace will substitute value of the variable.

So the end value will be 4 empty arrays

```
${item} will become $a, ie: $a = array();
${item} will become $b, ie: $b = array();
${item} will become $c, ie: $c = array();
${item} will become $d, ie: $d = array();
```